# Sharing state up/down Rx stream

Tags: javascript, animation, reactive-programming, rxjs

I am learning reactive programming and rxjs. As a proof of concept I picked an interactive animation I have in my application. The application is composed of 36 frames (images). When the user drags with the mouse left/right, the frames flip in cyclic sequence, producing the animation effect.

Out of the 36 frames, there are four key frames (0, 9, 18, 27). When the user releases mouse, the animation continues, until one of the key frames is reached.
I.e. when the user releases the mouse at frame 4, while dragging right, the animation displays 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 with interval and then stops.

A plunker with my reactive implementation can be found here: http://plnkr.co/edit/cM42VkTQgydyofsW47cj?p=preview Instead of images it displays just a div with frame number in it, to show the idea.

This almost works. It detects start/end of dragging. It animates with timer. The timer animation gets interrupted when user starts dragging again.
What does not work is, that when the user stops dragging at a certain frame, e.g. 12, the timer animation goes up to frame 18 and stops. When the user starts dragging again, it flips back to 12 and starts from there, instead of frame 18. The problem is, my timer animation does not update the current frame number.

The problem can be easily solved by storing the current frame number in a variable and referring to it from the streams. It does not seem to follow the reactive patter though. My question is, how could I manage the state (current frame in this case) in the streams?

The way I implement the frame calculation and some explanation of my code below.

I create three event-based streams: `panStartStream` for mouse-down event, `panStream` for mouse-move and `panEndStream` for mouse-up.

In `panStart` I use map to generate a stream of related pan events (`panStream`) terminated by `panEndStream`. Kind of classic example from various rxjs presentations. This produces `panningStream` stream. There I extract `mouseX` (map), combine two subsequent events into one and determine delta, which I then use to calculate frame delta.

Next is `panningDetectionStream`, which has an event for panning start and panning end. In panning end I store last delta, I use it afterwards to determine direction of timer-based animation.

`panningRotationStream` is the one, where I calculate frame number to be displayed as long as the user is dragging the mouse. There I simply flatten sequence of `panStream`s with `concatAll`, calculate the accumulative frame number from deltas (`scan`) and normalize it to 0-35 range to wrap the animation.

Last stream is `rotationStream`. Here I compose `panningRotationStream` and `panningDetectionStream` together, so that I can discover, when the user stops panning. As long as the user is panning, I pass the frame number to the subscriber. If the panning has been finished on key frame, I do nothing. If the panning has been finished on intermediate frame, I generate sequence of frames between the current one and main frame, each delayed with some timer. This this then flattened down to the main stream with `concatAll`.

The problem is, I have to calculate the frame number while panning. I need it to determine number of frames in the timer-based sequence. Then in the timer-animation I would need to update this value, so that next time panning starts this value is used as the base. But I do not see the way to push this value up the stream. I was considering some options like combining two deltas (one from panning, one from animation) together into a frame number, generating always 8 timer-based frames and filtering them on merged stream, after reaching key frame, etc. All my ideas increase complexity and do not seem right.
How could I do it in a nice and 'reactive' way?

Comment: Please come up with an implementation idea of your own and we might be able to improve it.

Comment: @OliverWeichhold Updated plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/7YtG9jHhatvm92JQNmyd?p=preview Swiching to deltas simplified the timer-generation frames. I now generate 8 timer frames, no matter where the animation currently is and ignore the excessive ones when calculating the actual frame number.

Comment: And a sample with using side-effects and variables to hold the current state: http://plnkr.co/edit/wupIZySg5LikvOJPRKmB?p=preview